# IKImageBrowserView and highlighting a specific image based on state

Tags: image, macos, swift, cocoa, ikimagebrowserview

So I have a IKImageBrowser full of images that I pull from a core data. The image itself isn't in core data just the reference to it.  I'm trying to figure out a way to indicate that a specific image is disabled.  Like a red border around it. This status will come from core data of that specific image.

I've looked over the IKImageBrowserView and IKImageBrowserCell in the docs to see if there is anything I can use but can't seem to find anything.

I just need a way to visually highlight or make an image standout when it's disabled.  Any Ideas or docs that you can point me to?

Comment: Subclassing is your way to go. Check sources https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ImageBrowser/Listings/ImageBrowserController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003997-ImageBrowserController_m-DontLinkElementID_4 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/ImageBrowser/ImageBrowser.html and GOOGLE "IKImageBrowserView site:developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/"

Comment: So would I subclass IKImageBrowserCell?

Comment: If you don't want to implement the same what's out there you should start with subclassing IKImageBrowserCell. Create a sample project and play with it. There might be other solutions but you have to use the search term above. You have to research this on your own behalf.

Comment: Thank you.  I've already got the subclassing to work.

Comment: @RyanKnopp If you got it to work, would you mind, adding it as an answer? It is an interesting question...